# Print out elements in a hash table, Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have a hash table that looks like this:

```
hash =
"{\"url\":\"/system/message\",\"device\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-08-28T11:16:29.516617Z\",\"object\":{\"timestamp\":\"2018-08-28T11:16:29.516490Z\",\"id\":9800,\"debug_level\":2,\"message\":\"Got new port configuration\"}}"

 hash.each do |variable|
    puts variable
 end
```

This do not work

Comment: That's not a hash, though. It's a string.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to first convert your string to a hash.

```
require 'json'

my_hash = JSON.parse(hash)
my_hash.each do |key, value|
  puts value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
require 'json'
values = JSON.parse(hash).map {|k,v| puts v }
```